# Metal flashing for covered porch wall cap (other options) - some exposure to 8 months of rain

Tags: flashing

[image: metal guard wall flashing detail]

[image: seam detail]

[image]

I have a covered porch with two structural columns embedded in the guard wall.  They have welded metal flanged which even if not already embedded in finishings (cedar soffit / guard wall) would not allow a seamless collar to be installed.

The siding for the house is standing seam metal and the siding guy capped the wall as shown.  I am not sure what other options he had but the seam details are out of character for the finish level of the house.

What other options are there for this detail?  Someone suggested forming a concrete cap and pouring in place.  I think this option would be too bulky and quite difficult to do.  The other thought I had was to get something made out of a thick gauge of steel and welded and ground on site to match the two column penetrations.  I'd still be left with whatever clearance between the columns and the cap penetration but at least the surface seam details could be done nicely.

In terms of budget I am thinking it would be nice to get it under $3000.  Recommendations for material, other ideas?

Comment: it looks like he did as good a job as could be expected, if that's cedar and zinc they'll be the same colour in a few years

Comment: I think most flashing here are galvalume which is a carbon steel sheet coated with aluminum-zinc alloy by a continuous hot-dip process. The nominal coating composition is 55% aluminum and 45% zinc. A small but important addition of silicon is included in the coating alloy. It is added not to enhance the corrosion performance, but to provide good coating adhesion to the steel substrate when the product is roll-formed, drawn, or bent during fabrication.

Comment: @jasen Ignoring the wall flashing interface I agree - I don't know what else he could have done but the end result isn't pretty.  Any thoughts on other options?  I tried looking for google images of post penetrations into wall caps but didn't come up with much.